# How to render json with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is 3 models: Place, Cafe, Club; they are connected through polymorhic relations ('details' field in Place model and 'place' field in Cafe & Club models). So, I want to render information about all places with details (i.e. with fields of Cafe & Club models) in JSON - for this purpose I overrides as_json method:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(include: :details))
  end
```

It works good, now JSON renders information by all places with 'details' key. Now there is FoodType model, and only Cafe is connected to this model through has_many; I want to render all places with details and food_types for Cafe. How can I do it? I thought I could override as_json for Cafe and all would be good:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(include: [:food_types]))
  end
```

But it didn't work. Please, tell me, how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods. It has many good examples that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not override `to_json` or `as_json`. They are there for a purpose. What if you need the object's json elsewhere without those relations? It's hard to solve if you have already overridden `as_json` to a certain style.

Use whatever the following gems: ActiveModel Serializers, rabl, jbuilder. Either of them can handle your request super easily.